# se puede hacer una tabla dentro de un tab de vuetify?

Tags: javascript, html, vuetify

hola tengo un tab y dentro del mismo quería crear una tabla don diversos datos , el problema es que no se como hacerlo ,como puedo hacer una tabla dentro de un tab o crearla en HTML por ejemplo y mostrarla con tab?

mi codigo js:

```
tab:[   { tab: 'Otro'                  , content: 'Contenido' },
        { tab: 'Otro1'                 , content: 'Contenido' },
        { tab: 'Otro2'                 , content: 'Contenido' },
]

html:
    <template>
  <v-data-table
  :headers="comercios"
  :items="desserts"
  :items-per-page="10"
   ></v-data-table>
   </template>
```

Comment: Hola Rodrigo, veo que estas usando Vuetify y Vue, lograste recolver esto? si tienes alguna duda escribeme a christiangtzv@gmail.com con gusto te ayudo

Comment: hola no pude hacerlo correctamente ,así que claro, te escribo gracias